# What's wrong in this simple python code?

Tags: python

Why is it not giving out correct total of first even fibonacci numbers upto 4 mn?

```
x = 1
y = 2
list = [1,2]
while y< 4000000:
    z= x+y
    x=y
    y=z
    list.append (y)
list_even = []
for a in list:
    if a%2 == 0:
        list_even.append (a)
else:
    pass

total = sum(list_even)
print (total)
```

Comment: `x=y; y= x+y` is wrong.

Comment: even after correcting, the total is wrong.

Comment: `else: pass` is not necessary. Just remove it.

Comment: Removed. But how to get correct total?

Comment: @Rizz_Beginner_Python correct answer is `4613732`, not `508186`.

Comment: 4613732 I am also getting. Thanks.

Comment: You're asking for help debugging, but it's not clear what steps you've already taken other than noting that the answer is "wrong". For example, how did you check the first part of your code is generating fibonacci numbers correctly?

Comment: Thank You everyone. The code was correct inn first place. It was just that the answer I knew was wrong.

Comment: BTW @paul hanking, I printed the lists at every stage and confirmed they were correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are other answers already addressing specific bugs in your code, so I want to offer a completely different implementation that achieves your stated goal:

> giving out correct total of first even fibonacci numbers upto 4 mn

If you want to find the sum of the even Fibonacci numbers up to some limit, the code below might be a more functional way of achieving it. It's based on composing Python generators, which should help make the code easier to follow and more reusable.

```
def fib():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

def evens(l):
    for x in l:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            yield x

def sum_even_fibonacci(limit):
    total = 0

    for x in evens(fib()):
        if total + x > limit:
            return total

        total += x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sum_even_fibonacci(4000000))
```

**Output**

```
1089154
```

**Edit**

It's ambiguous what exactly OP is asking.

- If OP wants to sum the even Fibonacci terms *until the sum would surpass 4,000,000*, then the answer is what I stated above - 1089154.
- If OP wants to sum *all even Fibonacci terms under 4,000,000*, then the expression `if total + x > limit` would change to `x > limit` and the answer would be 4613732.

Comment: the condition should be `x>limit`

Comment: @Copperfield It depends on how the question is interpreted, before OP completely mangled it. I interpreted 4,000,000 as being the limit on the *total* (i.e. keep adding the even Fibonacci terms up until 4,000,000 is surpassed).

Comment: the OP wants the sum of the evens fibonacci numbers less than 4.000.000 that much is clear since the begging

Comment: I never changed the part -"Why is it not giving out correct total of first even fibonacci numbers upto 4 mn?"

Answer (score 2):

I recognize this as [Problem 2](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2) on Project Euler. For some reason, @Tagc is getting the wrong answer. I used a generator as well but not a list. Here was my solution:

```python
def fibonacci():
    term_0, term_1 = 1,2
    while True:
        yield term_0 + term_1
        term_0, term_1 = term_1, term_0 + term_1

fibonacci_sum = 2
for n in fibonacci():
    if n > 4000000: break
    if n % 2 == 0: fibonacci_sum += n

print(fibonacci_sum)
```

Output:

```bash
$ python 002.py
4613732
```

Comment: I'm getting a different answer because I'm interpreting the question a different way. OP's problem is ambiguous, but your interpretation is more likely to be correct if it's a Project Euler problem. I get the same answer as you if I change `total + x > limit` to `x > limit`.

Comment: @Tagc, oh that makes more sense, you're finding the largest sum less than 4000000.

Answer (score 2):

just for fun, this is an one liner version

```
from itertools import takewhile

def fib():
    fk, fk1 = 0,1
    while True:
        yield fk
        fk, fk1 = fk1, fk+fk1

print( sum( x for x in takewhile(lambda f:f<4000000,fib()) if x%2==0 ) )
```

here [takewhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) will stop the iteration when the condition is no longer satisfied the same way as the others answers